# Wordpress custom template doesn't support shortcodes

Tags: wordpress

I have created a blank template using these instructions... https://tips.initpals.com/wordpress-tips/how-to-create-a-blank-page-template-in-wordpress/

```
<?php /* Template Name: Blank Template */?>
<?php
    if (have_posts()) {
        while (have_posts()): the_post();
        echo strip_tags(get_the_content(), '<p> <a>');
        endwhile;
    }
?>
```

...but now any pages using that template doesn't support shortcodes.

What is the code to enable support for shortcodes?  I am NOT looking for the `do_shortcode()` function as it only runs a specific shortcode... I want the shortcode to be specified in the page and not the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `do_shortcode()` ?

> Search content for shortcodes and filter shortcodes through their
> hooks. If there are no shortcode tags defined, then the content will
> be returned without any filtering. This might cause issues when
> plugins are disabled but the shortcode will still show up in the post
> or content.

*Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/*

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ):
  while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
    if ( get_the_content() !== '' ):
      echo do_shortcode( get_the_content() );
    endif; 
  endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

Untested but should be working.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed... In the original post I said I did not want the `do_shortcode()` function because I didn't want to specify a specific shortcode but your answer shows how to use it right

Comment: `echo do_shortcode( the_content() );` should be `echo do_shortcode( get_the_content()  );`, as `the_content()` function passes the content through `the_content` filter (which parses shortcodes) and automatically echoes the result. `echo` is also only needed on `get_the_content()` not `the_content`

Comment: @Xhynk Thanks, will update answer, I think you're referring to the `esc_html()` applied to `get_the_content` by `the_content()` ?

Comment: @amarinediary - Nope. both `get_the_content()` and `the_content()` are WP functions. `the_content` is also the name of a filter. `the_content()` function passes everything through `the_content` filter, then outputs it for you, while `get_the_content()` does none of those (basically just gets the `post_content` field from the database. See: [`get_the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/) and [`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that [`get_the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/) does **not** pass the content of the post through [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) filter, which is responsible for expanding shortcodes and stuff.

Also, you state you don't want [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) because it "only runs a specific shortcode". That's incorrect, it will actually parse any and all shortcodes in the string that's passed to it.

If you were to use [`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) function, it does use `the_content` filter, parses shortcodes, and echoes the result automatically. If you're using `get_the_content()`, you'll need to either pass it through `do_shortcode()` or apply `the_content` filter to it using [`apply_filters()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/) before manually outputting the result.

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
```

as well as

```
echo do_shortcode( get_the_content() );
```

Will parse all the shortcodes in the content that is passed along.

Comment: Thanks... I hadn't clued in originally but that is essentially what @amarinediary was trying to tell me... Thanks to both of you